# Is it possible to query the Blockchain API to get information on currency exchanges?

Tags: blockchain

Coinbase stopped publishing it's user stats in 2017, so I haven't been able to find a way to see how many users currently use the exchange.

My (albeing limited) understanding is I should be able to work this information out from querying the Blockchain.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am not sure about Ccinbase, but i know that a lot of exchanges creates completely different wallets(addresses) for each user, so its impossible to track them. You can do it for decentralized exchanges as Idex/Bancor/0x etc, because they are using specific smart-contract(only in Ethereum network)